# How to use setup and use iconv library

Tags: c++, c

I need to use incov library to convert ASCII text file to UTF-8. I am using Visual Studio 2008. Can some one guide how to do this kind of stuff. Tried to google it, but did not understand from where to get library files and how to use them.

Comment: Is there a reason that you must to use iconv, instead of doing it some other way?

Comment: I have the text file in MacRoman, and I need to convert it UTF-8. I need to use iconv.

Comment: yes, but why does it HAVE to be iconv? why isn't any other option allowed? there might be simpler ways, which don't require using iconv.

Comment: That is what my requirement is!! thats why it should be iconv.

Comment: A requirement to convert MacRoman is not a requirement to use iconv. The Win32 API can do this conversion, as can icu4c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text that you have really ISO-646 or 'plain old ASCII', it is already UTF-8.

If it is, in fact, some other encoding that uses all 256 values of the bytes, you will find it much easier to call `MultiByteToWideChar` to get UTF-16 and then call `WideCharToMultiByte` to get UTF-8.

You will need a temporary buffer of `wchar_t` to store the intermediate UTF-16 result. This works regardless of compiler version or settings or runtime, these are Win32 APIs, not language runtime APIs.

MacRoman is code page 10000, so you can definitely handle it this way. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719641(v=prot.10).aspx

You might also find ICU4C easier to get working on Windows than iconv.

Comment: I have the text file in MacRoman, and I need to convert it UTF-8. I need to use iconv.

Comment: If I have to use MultiByteToWideChar I need to use wchar_t strings right? I am not sure my compiler supports that. Charactor Set was set to Use Multi-byte Character Set, Common Language Runtime Support was set to No Common Language Runtime Support.

Comment: You need a temporary buffer of wchar_t on the way.

Comment: `const int nBufLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF16, 0, macRomanString.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL); 
const int err = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, unicodeString.c_str(), -1, temp, nBufLen, NULL, NULL);` 
Does this works

Comment: No, it's not CP_UTF16 you want, but rather the number for mac roman from the page I linked.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to convert ASCII to UTF-8 is `strcpy` or `memcpy`...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit misleading as Mac Roman is not the same as ASCII.

The instructions for download and installation of LibIconv for Windows can be found [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)

Comment: I am confused too, if I am not confusing you guys much, let me make it clear here. I have a text file which is in German, I am not sure whether its MacRoman or ASCII. But I need to convert it to UTF-8. I am completely new to these text formats.

Comment: If it is in German than it is not ASCII, as it doesn't have same characters, e.g. those  with umlauts. However, without knowing the encoding / code page, I am not sure if it is possible to properly convert it.

Comment: Ok are there any other ways to convert that file to UTF 8?

Comment: First you will need to know the original codepage. You can find it by comparing the value  of e.g. 'ö' with those in Mac Roman of Win-1250 codepage. When you know that, just use the APIs mentioned in the answer by bmargulies.